# The multivariate distribution calculating $Cov(X_1, X_2)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, covariance

**Question**
Let $x = [X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4]^T$ be a multivariate and normal random vector and
$$
\mu = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
-1 \\
2 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}, 
\Sigma =\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 1 &0 & 2 \\
1 & 4 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 9 & 3 \\
2 & 0 & 3 & 9
\end{bmatrix},
$$

Find $Cov(X_1, X_2)$

---

Is it possible to find the Covariance of $X_1$ and $X_2$ by looking at these two matrices?

Comment: Would this just be $\Sigma_{12} = 1$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, the density function of the $\ x\ $ in your question is
$$
\frac{\displaystyle e^{-(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)}}{(2\pi)^2\sqrt{\det \Sigma}}\ ,
$$
in which case $\ \Sigma\ $ is the covariance matrix of $\ \big[X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4\big]^T\ $, and your surmise that $\ Cov\big(X_1,X_2\big)=\Sigma_{12}\ $ is correct.